# JQuery Ajax function not being executed in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome extension which uses simple HTTP POST requests. It's my first javascript code ever. I used [POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/) to generate this code which fulfills the requirement (POSTMAN worked with the POST request).

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("email", "XXX");
form.append("password", "XXX");

var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://xxx.xxx.in/xxx/",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "fa86846e-4030-d90f-701a-82e36e6117b0"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "contentType": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "data": form
};

chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log("outside")
try {
  chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log("inside try block")
  $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log("inside")
    chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log(response);
  });
} catch (e) {
  chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log("Exception caught")
  chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log(e)
} finally {

}
```

I tried it with a chrome extension but my console does not log after the `inside try block`. I can't understand what happened in this line
`$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {`

The error is not caught anywhere else. I have given appropriate permissions in my `manifest.json` file.

I have some very specific questions to ask:

1. What is the best workaround for requests? XmlHttpRequests or JQuery
2. What are some best ways of debugging javascript applications? That would help a lot, thanks.

Comment: use `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` - jquery wont work unless you can include it in your extension - and for only one function ($.ajax), jquery is huge overkill for little benefit

Comment: Can you explain where this code is and _why are you using `getBackgroundPage()` this way_? That would explain how to debug this.